# Importing "0000" or "0030" into DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

I am importing values like 0000,0002,0023,0034 from a text file. However, the table shows them as 0, 2, 23, 34. Does anyone know why it is removing the leading zeros?

Here is my code:

```
private DataTable ImportTabFile()
{
    string dataSourcePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\Desktop";
    string dataFileName = "ACTIVITYEX.txt";
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dataSourcePath + @";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited""";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", dataFileName);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

How can I keep the leading zeroes during the import?

here is what my schema file looks like:

```
[ACTIVITYEX.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
ColNameHeader=False
Col13=ErrorCode Text
```

Comment: That's because it thinks they are numbers, so the leading 0 are irrelevant...

Comment: What *type* of fields are they? Leading 0's are fictitious for numeric.

Comment: @pst they are all just regular text

Comment: [Select is not broken.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx)

Comment: @thomas how do i make it think otherwiose?>

Comment: @I__: Can you show the insertion code.

Comment: @anthony what do u mean?

Comment: @anth can you summarize please?

Comment: @I__: No it's not. You aren't showing the insertion code.

Comment: @I__, I don't know how to fix it, or I would have posted an answer, not a comment...

Comment: @I__ how did the data get into the database? How do you know it's just a text field.

Comment: @john its not in a db its just in a text file

Comment: @thomas its in a txtfile

Comment: Why was this downvoted? it's a perfectly valid question...

Comment: @nija its a text file not a db

Comment: @I__: Yea, I've made some edits to my previous comment. :) My point still stands: You aren't showing your insertion code. You should edit the OP to include how you are inserting the data.

Comment: @nija all the code that i have is shown there

Comment: @Nija - the database is a comma separated text file. He probably "inserted" the data via Notepad.

Comment: @I__: If that's all the code you have; Then we aren't going to be able to help you. If the data is in the txt file as 0,2... then we need to see the insertion code. If it's in the file as 0000,0002... then we need to see the display code. Not the 'select' statement.

Comment: And I assume the question is meant to read "and when I look in my database they are being **returned** like this"

Comment: @Nija, stop being hung up over "insertion code." There is none. **This isn't about a database.**

Comment: @todda you are correct He probably "inserted" the data via Notepad.

Comment: @jay even after correcting the schema file, im still having the same issue. the schema is shown in the updated question

Comment: @everyone similar question to this and no answers again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747776/importing-csv-files-using-oledb-string-datatype

Comment: @|__: You need to specify all columns in the schema. I tried it with `0000,0002,0023` in the text file and it didn't work if I only specified `Col3`, but worked when I specified all 3.

Comment: and same exact question here http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/843129-missing-leading-zeros-parsed-csv-file-schema-ini-not-working-me

Comment: @joel make that into an answer THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @|__: It's really todda.speot.is's answer that is correct. The schema.ini documentation he linked says to specify each column, so his answer really was spot-on. Mark his accepted, please. :)

Comment: @Joel - I can't take all the credit! I'm sure someone else mentioned the same thing in one of the 50 or so comments :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JET will infer types based on the first row. It is probably inferring your fields are `INT` because `0000` can be converted to a number. As mentioned above, leading zeroes are useless.

You can use [`schema.ini`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx) to explicitly define the column types. As noted in the comments above, you need to specify each column as per the documentation:

> **You must specify each column** by number **and designate the column name, data type, and width for fixed-length files**.

Alternatively [this article](http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/knowledge-base/tableau-does-not-correctly-recognize-excel-columns) has some information on controlling how the types are inferred.

Comment: +1 beat me to it (and I had my answer ready to post).  I was going to add that he can also programmatically construct his DataTable and define the column he's having problems with as string and fill that.

Comment: I normally don't reply to these sorts of questions but I felt sorry for the guy because the comments to his question border on moronic.

Comment: And I would not have thought to construct the `DataTable` and explicitly specify the column types. You have a very good point.

Comment: I thought it was a good question.  I forgot about schema.ini and I'm glad to be reminded of it.

Comment: @todd thanks so much for your help,. is it possible to do this without effecting the registry?