# OPENROWSET - how to read everything as text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, openrowset

I am using the following command to load data into SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO [NewTable]

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET 
(
'MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=c:\SomeFolder\;'
, 'SELECT * from [SomeFile.csv]'
);
```

The problem is that apparently the driver tries to guess the datatype for each field, and where the cast fails it simply reads in a null. For example, lets say I have the following

```
SomeCode   SomeName
100        A
299        B
22         C
123        D
ABC        E
900        F
```

It seems to figure that "SomeCode" is an integer, and it will read "ABC" as NULL. Is there any way I can stop this from happening. All I want is for the data to be handled as varchars all the way through.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the second link in my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209942/importing-0000-or-0030-into-datatable) about registry keys that control how JET infers types.

> You may also want to make sure the ImportMixedTypes key is set to Text.
>
> `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\ImportMixedTypes`

You might have to substitute in something else for `Excel`, however.

Comment: Is "Microsoft Text Driver", which I am using in the command above, the same as JET in this regard?

Comment: I believe so, yes. The text driver is implemented as a JET ISAM.

Answer (score 2):

It'll scan only a few rows to determine most probable datatype. This is an issue in scenarios like yours. However you can use a format file together with `OPENROWSET`.

Details on how to format your `FORMATFILE` when reading text files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191175.aspx

In your case:

Make a formatfile.xml containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Col1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Col2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Change your query to:

```
BULK INSERT [newTable]
FROM 'C:\somefile.csv' 
WITH (formatfile='C:\formatfile.xml');
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass a format file into into the insert command without creating it as an XML file first? I need to actually load hundreds of files with different layouts for which I need to generate the upload process on the fly. Don't really want to create hundres of xml format files as well.

Comment: I think you should look at the answer below for that. It might be better to change the default behavior of the importing engine for your case.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find what I was looking for so adding it here since this is one of the top results:

If you are using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB and are having this issue then you need to add the option "IMEX=1;" (without the quotes) to the data source.

Example:

`SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Database=P:\Data\FileName.xlsx'
                    ,'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:BB100]')`

This will read mixed data as text.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

a shortcut to solve this problem is to use "HDR=No".
in this case, because of the header datatType (Text), the default value of the columns whoud be text.
at the end, you could simply filter the header row. 
in your case:

```
INSERT INTO [NewTable]

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET 
(
'MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=c:\SomeFolder\;'
;HDR=Noe, 'SELECT * from [SomeFile.csv]'
)where [F1] <> 'SomeCode';
```